# Maximum Likelihood in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to use maximum likelihood to estimate the normal linear model in Julia. I have used the following code to simulate the process with just an intercept and an anonymous function per the Optim documentation regarding values that do not change:

```
using Optim

nobs = 500
nvar = 1
β = ones(nvar)*3.0
x = [ones(nobs) randn(nobs,nvar-1)]
ε = randn(nobs)*0.5
y = x*β + ε

function LL_anon(X, Y, β, σ)
  -(-length(X)*log(2π)/2 - length(X)*log(σ) - (sum((Y - X*β).^2) / (2σ^2)))
end
LL_anon(X,Y, pars) = LL_anon(X,Y, pars...)

res2 = optimize(vars -> LL_anon(x,y, vars...), [1.0,1.0]) # Start values: β=1.0, σ=1.0
```

This actually recovered the parameters and I received the following output:

```
 * Algorithm: Nelder-Mead
 * Starting Point: [1.0,1.0]
 * Minimizer: [2.980587812647935,0.5108406803949835]
 * Minimum: 3.736217e+02
 * Iterations: 47
 * Convergence: true
   *  √(Σ(yᵢ-ȳ)²)/n < 1.0e-08: true
   * Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: false
 * Objective Calls: 92
```

However, when I try and set nvar = 2, i.e. an intercept plus an additional covariate, I get the following error message:

```
MethodError: no method matching LL_anon(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  LL_anon(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at In[297]:2
  LL_anon(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Any, ::Any) at In[113]:2
  LL_anon(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at In[297]:4
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] (::##245#246)(::Array{Float64,1}) at .\In[299]:1
 [2] value!!(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\NLSolversBase\src\interface.jl:9
 [3] initial_state(::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Void}, ::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/solvers/zeroth_order\nelder_mead.jl:136
 [4] optimize(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Void}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\optimize.jl:25
 [5] #optimize#151(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Tuple{##245#246}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:62
 [6] #optimize#148(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:52
 [7] optimize(::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:52
```

I'm not sure why adding an additional variable is causing this issue but it seems like a type instability problem.

The second issue is that when I use my original working example and set the starting values to [2.0,2.0], I get the following error message:

```
log will only return a complex result if called with a complex argument. Try log(complex(x)).

Stacktrace:
 [1] nan_dom_err at .\math.jl:300 [inlined]
 [2] log at .\math.jl:419 [inlined]
 [3] LL_anon(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64, ::Float64) at .\In[302]:2
 [4] (::##251#252)(::Array{Float64,1}) at .\In[304]:1
 [5] value(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\NLSolversBase\src\interface.jl:19
 [6] update_state!(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Optim.NelderMeadState{Array{Float64,1},Float64,Array{Float64,1}}, ::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/solvers/zeroth_order\nelder_mead.jl:193
 [7] optimize(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Void}, ::Optim.NelderMeadState{Array{Float64,1},Float64,Array{Float64,1}}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\optimize.jl:51
 [8] optimize(::NLSolversBase.NonDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.NelderMead{Optim.AffineSimplexer,Optim.AdaptiveParameters}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Void}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\optimize.jl:25
 [9] #optimize#151(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Tuple{##251#252}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\dolacomb\.julia\v0.6\Optim\src\multivariate/optimize\interface.jl:62
```

Again, I’m not sure why this is happening and since start values are very important I’d like to know how to overcome this issue and they are not too far off from the true values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Splatting causes the problem. E.g. it transforms `[1, 2, 3]` into three parameters while your function accepts only two.

Use the following call:

```
res2 = optimize(vars -> LL_anon(x,y, vars[1:end-1], vars[end]), [1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

and you can remove the following line from your code

```
LL_anon(X,Y, pars) = LL_anon(X,Y, pars...)
```

or replace it with:

```
LL_anon(X,Y, pars) = LL_anon(X,Y, pars[1:end-1], pars[end])
```

but it would not be called by optimization routine unless you change a call to:

```
res2 = optimize(vars -> LL_anon(x,y, vars), [1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

Finally - to get good performance of this code I would recommend to wrap it all in a function.

EDIT: now I see a second question. The reason is that `σ` can become negative in the optimization process and then `log(σ)` fails. The simplest thing to do in this case is to take `log(abs(σ)))` like this:

```
function LL_anon(X, Y, β, σ)
    -(-length(X)*log(2π)/2 - length(X)*log(abs(σ)) - (sum((Y - X*β).^2) / (2σ^2)))
end
```

Of course then you have to take absolute value of `σ` as a solution as you might get a negative value from optimization routine.

A cleaner way would be to optimize over e.g. `log(σ)` not `σ` like this:

```
function LL_anon(X, Y, β, logσ)
    -(-length(X)*log(2π)/2 - length(X)*logσ - (sum((Y - X*β).^2) / (2(exp(logσ))^2)))
end
```

but then you have to use `exp(logσ)` to recover `σ` after optimization finishes.

Comment: Thank you for this bit of information! I now have several methods to look at and decide which way to proceed.

Comment: Just as an additional general comment: you might want to look for other optimization routines than `optim` if you have a more complex constrained optimization tasks, e.g. https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but I have to take baby steps first!

Answer (score 1):

I have asked around regarding this and have another option. The main reason for looking at this problem is twofold. One, to learn how to use the optimization routines in Julia in a canonical situation and two, to expand this to spatial econometric models. With that in mind, I'm posting the other suggested code from the Julia message board so that others may see another solution.

```
using Optim

nobs = 500
nvar = 2
β = ones(nvar) * 3.0
x = [ones(nobs) randn(nobs, nvar - 1)]
ε = randn(nobs) * 0.5
y = x * β + ε

function LL_anon(X, Y, β, log_σ)
    σ = exp(log_σ)
    -(-length(X) * log(2π)/2 - length(X) * log(σ) - (sum((Y - X * β).^2) / (2σ^2)))
end

opt = optimize(vars -> LL_anon(x,y, vars[1:nvar], vars[nvar + 1]),
               ones(nvar+1))

# Use forward autodiff to get first derivative, then optimize
fun1 = OnceDifferentiable(vars -> LL_anon(x, y, vars[1:nvar], vars[nvar + 1]),
                         ones(nvar+1))
opt1 = optimize(fun1, ones(nvar+1))

Results of Optimization Algorithm

Algorithm: L-BFGS
Starting Point: [1.0,1.0,1.0]
Minimizer: [2.994204150985705,2.9900626550063305, …]
Minimum: 3.538340e+02
Iterations: 12
Convergence: true
|x - x’| ≤ 1.0e-32: false
|x - x’| = 8.92e-12
|f(x) - f(x’)| ≤ 1.0e-32 |f(x)|: false
|f(x) - f(x’)| = 9.64e-16 |f(x)|
|g(x)| ≤ 1.0e-08: true
|g(x)| = 6.27e-09
Stopped by an increasing objective: true
Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: false
Objective Calls: 50
Gradient Calls: 50

opt1.minimizer
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
  2.9942 
  2.99006
 -1.0651  #Note: needs to be exponentiated

# Get Hessian, use Newton!
fun2 = TwiceDifferentiable(vars -> LL_anon(x, y, vars[1:nvar], vars[nvar + 1]),
                           ones(nvar+1))
opt2 = optimize(fun2, ones(nvar+1))

Results of Optimization Algorithm

Algorithm: Newton’s Method
Starting Point: [1.0,1.0,1.0]
Minimizer: [2.99420415098702,2.9900626550079026, …]
Minimum: 3.538340e+02
Iterations: 9
Convergence: true
|x - x’| ≤ 1.0e-32: false
|x - x’| = 1.36e-11
|f(x) - f(x’)| ≤ 1.0e-32 |f(x)|: false
|f(x) - f(x’)| = 1.61e-16 |f(x)|
|g(x)| ≤ 1.0e-08: true
|g(x)| = 6.27e-09
Stopped by an increasing objective: true
Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: false
Objective Calls: 45
Gradient Calls: 45
Hessian Calls: 9
fieldnames(fun2)

13-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :f       
 :df      
 :fdf     
 :h       
 :F       
 :DF      
 :H       
 :x_f     
 :x_df    
 :x_h     
 :f_calls 
 :df_calls
 :h_calls 

opt2.minimizer
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
  2.98627
  3.00654
 -1.11313

numerical_hessian = (fun2.H) #.H is the numerical Hessian
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 64.8715      -9.45045      0.000121521
 -0.14568     66.4507       0.0        
  1.87326e-6   4.10675e-9  44.7214
```

From here, one can use the numerical Hessian to obtain the standard errors for the estimates and form t-statistics, etc. for their own functions.

Again, thank you for providing an answer and I hope people find this information useful.